# How can I change FontWeight of paragraph when FontFamily of a FlowDocument is set?

Tags: c#, wpf, paragraph, flowdocument

Imagine you have the following style for a `FlowDocument`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocument}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI regular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="LineHeight" Value="19"/>
</Style>
```

now this won't make it bold for some reason.

```
<Paragraph>
    <Bold>Is this bold?</Bold>
</Paragraph>
```

or even this

```
<Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{DynamicResource CMMsg_7114}" />
```

Keep in mind that if I don't set the parent `FontFamily` and use the default font both methods work just fine. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FontFamily` "Segoe UI **regular**" does not support bold characters. Change the `FontFamily` to "Segoe UI":

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocument}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="LineHeight" Value="19"/>
</Style>
```